# Is the EV3 compatible with a 3rd party I2C gyroscope?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, 3rd-party

The only detail I've found so far is that the pull-up resistor should be 82k ohm. I'm wondering If I could just get something like this [Adafruit Gyro/Accelerometer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2809?gclid=CjwKCAjwx7DeBRBJEiwA9MeX_HyCh8ZtTl6AoMw7PFnTufeo9q5BzX_bNvNc9-q1AC9_z_gSRSX8PBoCu0kQAvD_BwE)
and just hook it up to the SDA and SCL pins of the EV3 and use it like the Lego brand sensor with minimal modification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Mindstorms is incredibly hackable. You can use whatever 3rd-party analog, I2C, or UART devices you want with the EV3 brick. According to the [hardware developer kit documentation](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/338591/hardware_developer_kit.pdf):

> The EV3 platform supports the same level of I2C communication as MINDSTORMS NXT. This means that
>   system support a maximum of 9600 bit/s and maximum 32 bytes communication buffers. All I2C
>   communication is running within software drivers. External devices are required to include pull-up
>   resistors on both pin 5 and 6 on 82K ohm. If multiple sensors are used on the same bus the total
>   impedance needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Obviously, the standard Lego programming software will not be able to utilize custom devices, but pretty much any 3rd-party firmware will allow sending custom I2C read/writes.

Answer (score 1):

As MindS1 mentioned, I2C on the EV3 is a bit limited, so it really depends on what device you are connecting. There isn't really a way to tell if a device will work or not besides just trying it out. Even if it "meets the specs", there can still be timing issues that cause problems.

Dexter Industries has a [nice blog post](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/connecting-ev3-arduino/) about connecting EV3 to an Arduino via I2C. This includes a block they created for the official EV3 programming software that does generic I2C communications. One limitation is that although you can read up to 32 bits at a time, you can only write at most one byte at a time (this is a limitation of the EV3 firmware, not the Dexter Industries block). So if a device requires longer write messages it definitely won't work. Otherwise, as already mentioned, you will just have to try it and see what happens.

The [ev3dev](http://ev3dev.org) 3rd-party OS for EV3 has more robust I2C handling since is uses the standard Linux I2C interface. For example, you can write a program in Python [like this](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/1007#issuecomment-344684487).